# Using CSS Grid to separate an unordered list to different columns/rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to use CSS Grid to arrange an unordered list to three columns (first grid in the snippet), and then move one item from the list to a separate row by defining grid-template-areas (second grid in the snippet).

Adding the `grid-template-areas` causes all the links with `grid-area: main-links` to stack up over each other.

Is this doable with CSS Grid without touching the HTML structure, or would it maybe require the use of subgrids which seem to be only available in Firefox?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 3rem 0.75rem;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid--areas {
  grid-template-areas:
    "main-links main-links main-links"
    "extra-links extra-links extra-links";
}

.grid--areas li {
  grid-area: main-links;    
}

.grid--areas .extra-link {
  grid-area: extra-links;
}
```

```html
<h3>Grid without template-areas</h3>
<p>Links in three columns</p>
<ul class="grid">
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
  <li>Link 5</li>
  <li>Link 6</li>
  <li>Link 7</li>
  <li>Link 8</li>
  <li>Link 9</li>
  <li>Link 10</li>
  <li class="extra-link">Extra link</li>
</ul>

<h3>Grid with template-areas</h3>
<p>Links should be in three columns with an extra link on a separate row</p>
<ul class="grid grid--areas">
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
  <li>Link 5</li>
  <li>Link 6</li>
  <li>Link 7</li>
  <li>Link 8</li>
  <li>Link 9</li>
  <li>Link 10</li>
  <li class="extra-link">Extra link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't use template areas for this. Just tell the elements which columns they should be in.

Comment: If you repeat the `"main-links main-links main-links"` line 5 times it works, but that means knowing how many links you have. I would say you need to rethink your strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Paulie_D, it seems I found a way to do this without the template-areas. I removed the template areas, specified two rows for the grid, and just setting a `grid-column` value on `extra-link` seems to drop it to a new row. (Did not understand why referring to the last row with `grid-row: -1` does not work though)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  gap: 3rem 0.75rem;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid--areas .extra-link {
  grid-column: 1;
}
```

```html
<h3>Grid without template-areas</h3>
<p>Links in three columns</p>
<ul class="grid">
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
  <li>Link 5</li>
  <li>Link 6</li>
  <li>Link 7</li>
  <li>Link 8</li>
  <li>Link 9</li>
  <li>Link 10</li>
  <li class="extra-link">Extra link</li>
</ul>

<h3>Grid with <s>template-areas</s> item set within the grid by referring to specific grid lines</h3>
<p>Links should be in three columns with an extra link on a separate row</p>
<ul class="grid grid--areas">
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
  <li>Link 3</li>
  <li>Link 4</li>
  <li>Link 5</li>
  <li>Link 6</li>
  <li>Link 7</li>
  <li>Link 8</li>
  <li>Link 9</li>
  <li>Link 10</li>
  <li class="extra-link">Extra link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can safely get rid of `grid-row: 0`. This value is invalid and won't affect your layout.

Comment: @FelipeSaldanha Thanks, just noticed that and adjusted the snippet. I did not fully understand why I was able to drop the extra link to the second row by defining the grid-column value instead of the grid-row though.

Comment: With `grid-column: 1` you're placing the extra link in the 1st vertical grid line. Then it starts in its own row because no other item can precede it.